# Running bash via ssh shows error: /usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, ssh, archlinux

Here is my test.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo succeed
```

When I run it from local, everything is all right:

```
[jerry@Jerry-DELL ~]$ ./test.sh
succeed
```

However, when i run it through ssh:

```
[jerry@Jerry-DELL ~]$ ssh localhost /home/jerry/test.sh
/usr/bin/env: 'bash': No such file or directory
```

Then, when i change “/usr/bin/env bash” to “/bin/bash”, it works:

```
[jerry@Jerry-DELL ~]$ ssh localhost /home/jerry/test.sh
succeed
```

So, what's the problem? How can i fix it? By the way, i use openssh8.6 on Manjaro.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `/bin` is in your `$PATH` (via ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc) when you do ssh.

To check it :

```
ssh localhost 'echo $PATH'
```